# Fro SQL (distinct) to firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have a tree structured in this way:

```
a:
  -id:a
  -location: 1
  -category: 10
b:
  -id:a
  -location: 1
  -category: 12
c:
  -id:a
  -location: 1
  -category: 14
d:
  -id:a
  -location: 2
  -category: 14
```

what I want are all categories for documents with location == 1.

In SQL I do:

```
Select distinct category where location = 1
```

How I can obtain same results in firebase?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to map SQL concepts to NoSQL databases is typically a guarantee for disappointment, so I'd recommend not going that route too often.

There is no concept of a distinct query in Firestore, so you will either have to:

- read all documents and determine the distinct categories in application code, or
- create an extra collection where you store the distinct categories, for example using the category value as the document ID.

Comment: I understood, unfortunately move from SQL to NoSQL it's a bit complicate, so your advice is to create a new collection where I put for example for each `location` the right categories?

Comment: Yeah, that seems like the most direct mapping. Typically in NoSQL you'll end up modeling in your database what you're showing on your screen. For a good intro, also see [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video), and [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Great! Thank you!